# $(x,\sin(\frac{1}{x}))$, $x>0$, homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $A=\{(x,\sin(\frac{1}{x}) | x>0\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I am trying to show this is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ which seems intuitively right as it is an infinite line, but I'm struggling to find an explicit homeomorphism.

Is there a way to show it is homeomorphic to  $(0,\infty)$, which is then homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3):

$e^{x}$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R$ onto $(0,\infty)$. And $x \to (x,\sin(\frac  1 x))$ is a homeomorphism from $(0,\infty)$ to $A$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $A\to (0, \infty)$ that takes $(x, y)\in A$ to $x$ is a homeomorphism. Its inverse is given by $x\mapsto(x, \sin(1/x))$. It's not difficult to see that they are both continuous and bijective on the given domains.

Comment: Uh, no mention of $e$ here. Projection continuous - check. Curve $\gamma(x)$ continuous - check. So (+1) here for best answer.

Comment: @DanRust The question asks "Is there a way to show it is homeomorphic to  $(0,\infty)$", and I have addressed that.

Comment: @DanRust No worries. Happens to me all the time too.

Answer (score 1):

For each $x>0$ define $f(x,\sin(1/x))=\log x$. Then $f^{-1}(t)=(e^t,\sin(e^{-t}))$ for each $t\in\Bbb R$.